# aws_eks_node_group Max pods disabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I am trying to create EKS cluster with maxpods limit =110

Creating node group using `aws_eks_node_group`

```
    resource "aws_eks_node_group" "eks-node-group" {
      cluster_name    = var.cluster-name
      node_group_name = var.node-group-name
      node_role_arn   = var.eks-nodes-role.arn
      subnet_ids      = var.subnet-ids
      version         = var.cluster-version
      release_version = nonsensitive(data.aws_ssm_parameter.eks_ami_release_version.value)
    
      capacity_type = "SPOT"
      lifecycle {
        create_before_destroy = true
      }
    
      scaling_config {
        desired_size = var.scale-config.desired-size
        max_size     = var.scale-config.max-size
        min_size     = var.scale-config.min-size
      }
      instance_types = var.scale-config.instance-types
    
      update_config {
        max_unavailable = var.update-config.max-unavailable
      }
    
      depends_on = [var.depends-on]
    
      launch_template {
        id      = aws_launch_template.node-group-launch-template.id
        version = aws_launch_template.node-group-launch-template.latest_version
      }
    }

    resource "aws_launch_template" "node-group-launch-template" {
      name_prefix = "eks-node-group"
      image_id    = var.template-image-id
    
      block_device_mappings {
        device_name = "/dev/sda1"
    
        ebs {
          volume_size = var.ebs_size
        }
      }
    
      ebs_optimized = true
    
      user_data = base64encode(data.template_file.test.rendered)
      # user_data = filebase64("${path.module}/example.sh")
    }
    
    data "template_file" "test" {
      template = <<EOF
    /etc/eks/bootstrap.sh ${var.cluster-name} --use-max-pods false --kubelet-extra-args '--max-pods=110'
      EOF
    }
```

Launch template is created just to provide bootstrap arguments. I have tried supplying the same in `aws_eks_cluster` resource as well

```
    module "eks__user_data" {
      source               = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws//modules/_user_data"
      version              = "18.30.3"
      cluster_name         = aws_eks_cluster.metashape-eks.name
      bootstrap_extra_args = "--use-max-pods false --kubelet-extra-args '--max-pods=110'"
    }
```

but unable to achieve desired effect till now.

Trying to follow
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cni-increase-ip-addresses.html. CNI driver is enabled 1.12 and all other configurations seems correct too.

Comment: There is no equals sign in the example you posted: `eksctl create nodegroup --cluster my-cluster --managed=false --max-pods-per-node 110`

Comment: i am not using eksctl.

Comment: Nevertheless, it's the command from the link you posted. The option is the same, isn't it?

Comment: i am using self managed group here. jsut above eksctl (which has =). but that example isn't exactly what my use case is as well. since i am using terraform

Comment: The issue seems to be with template_file data block itself

Comment: Yeah, my bad. So looking at the bootstrap script, I see no option to set the max number of pods there: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/blob/master/files/bootstrap.sh.